# Game center issue

Tags: game-center

Im New In Development think and i'm wondering about some things like the game center button , how to connect that button is there any ready code for that, the same question about the rate button . Can any one tell me how to do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//Rate Button

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"rateButton"]) //Your Rate Button name
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id919770861"]];//itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYourAppID
    }


//Game Center Button

 - (void)showGKGameCenterViewController:
(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (!_enableGameCenter) {
        NSLog(@"Local play is not authenticated");
    }
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterViewController =
    [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterViewController.viewState =
    GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
    [viewController presentViewController:gameCenterViewController
                                 animated:YES
                               completion:nil];
}

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"GameCenter"]) //Your Game Center Button Name
        {
            [self showGKGameCenterViewController:yourViewController];
        }
```